# Не работают эмулятор для Android

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор, genymotion

Не могу запустить эмуляторы: Genymotion после запуска вылетает, либо вообще не запускает, а эмулятор от Android Studio после прогрузки "Starting AVD" ничего не выдаёт.
Система: Ubuntu 16.04;

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с libGL

Необходимо установить

```
sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Найти путь к Android SDK и прилинковать файл

```
cd SDKPATH/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64
mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++
```

Если не запустится, ещё есть вариант подгрузить библиотеку при запуске студии, для этого необходимо прописать первой строкой в studio.sh

```
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6'
```

Если и это не поможет, то можно запустить эмулятор вручную с подгруженной библиотекой

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6' SDKPATH/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd <avd_name>
```

где avd_name название эмулируемого устройства

Comment: При попытки выполнить команду "sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i38" выдаёт "E: Не удалось найти пакет lib64stdc++6:i38
E: Не удалось найти пакет с помощью regex «lib64stdc++6»"

Comment: Поправил, там 386

Comment: Когда запускаю эмулятор вручную, выдаёт следующее "*** Error in `/root/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000004f5d9f0 ***
Аварийный останов (сделан дамп памяти)"